# Ordering of a field of rational forms over Q: Compare an arbitrary integer $n$ with an indeterminate $t$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working Exercise 6, section 1.2 in the book *A First Course in Real Analysis*, Berberian, Springer.

Let $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ be the field of rational forms (see def. below) over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ the set of all nonzero elements r(t)=p(t)/q(t) of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that the leading coefficients of $p$ and $q$ have the same sign, that is, such that $p(t) = a_{0} + a_{1}t + ... + a_{m}t^{m}$ and $q(t) = b_{0} + b_{1}t + ... + b_{n}t^{n}$ with $a_{m}b_{n} > 0$. Prove that:

1. $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ is an ordered field with $\mathbf{S}$ as set of positive elements.
2. For the ordering defined in (1), $n1 < t$ for every positive integer $n$.

Where a field of rational forms over F is defined by:

> Let $\mathbf{F}$ be any field.  Write $\mathbf{F}[t]$ for the set of all polynomials $p(t)=a_0+a_1t+\cdots+a_nt^n$ in an indeterminate $t$, with coefficients $a_k$ in $\mathbf{F}$.  Write $\mathbf{F}(t)$ for the set of all ratios $p(t)/q(t)$ with $p(t)$, $q(t) \in \mathbf{F}[t]$ and $q(t)$ is not the zero polynomial. $\mathbf{F}(t)$ is a field; it is called the field of rational forms over $\mathbf{F}$.

I can prove the first part but have no idea of the second part. It's very confusing to me whether $n1$ means $n\times1=n$ or it's a typo. Suppose that the author mean $n\times1$ then how could that be possible to compare $n$ with a variable $t$?

Comment: Not $\mathcal Q$ but $\Bbb Q.$ Not "...S *a* set of all..." but "$\mathcal S$ *the* set of all...". And not $nx1$ but $n\times1.$ And it is really $n\times1,$ i.e. $n$ times the element $1$ of $\Bbb Q(t).$

Comment: You *can* compare $n$ with $t:$ both are elements of your ordered field; prove that $t-n\in\mathcal S.$

Comment: @AnneBauval that is indeed quite pleasant to prove! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My shortcoming in interpreting $n$ as an element in $\mathbb{N}$ rather than an element of $\mathbb{Q}$ led to my failure to prove the second part. After seeing @Anne Bauval's comment, here's my proof for it:

First notice that $n$ and $1$ are all members of $\mathbb{Q}$, so $r(t) = (1t-n)/1 = t-n$ is a member of $\mathbf{S}$ since $1^{2} > 0$. So we have arrived to what we need to show.

Comment: 1) $\mathcal S,$ not $\Bbb S.$ 2) Typo: $r(t)=t-n1,$ not $t-1.$ 3) Simpler proof: $r(t)=(t-n)/1\in\mathcal S$ because in this fraction, the leading coefficients of numerator and denominator have the same sign: both are equal to $1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! I've edited as you suggested except for $\mathcal{S}$ cause $\mathbf{S}$ reflects what's in the book and is consistent with other field noation, i.e, $\mathbf{F}$.